# How to join two meshes with different number of loops

Tags: mesh, loop, retopology

I have modeled the head and the body of my character separately, and I’d like to join them.
However, the number of loops in the head is signficantly higher than in the body.
The only way I have found is using triangles to progressively simplify the neck topology towards the body, as shown in the image.

[image]

However, I am aware that non-quads are to be avoided.
Is there a better retopologization approach for this use case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tris are OK if it doesn't create any bad shading and pinching

Comment: https://topologyguides.com/loop-reduction might help to reduce the number of edge loops.

Comment: @Blunder your link is awesome! exactly what I was looking for